# Exclusion of files of certain extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a Windows cmd batch script named my.bat, I want to execute a command for all the files in the current directory except for the batch file my.bat.
I use below command in my.bat currently to run the command only for *.txt *.ppt, but really as new files of different extensions might be added to the folder and hence execution of this command by excluding one type of file extension (in my case *.bat) would be more readable/helpful.

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('dir /b *.txt *.ppt') DO echo %%i
```

Question is: How do I exclude that file alone with that particular file extension and make the for command execute on all files of all extensions except the excluded one?

Comment: One side query not related to above directly.If i need just the file extension to be printed i.e. "doc" , and not ".doc" which is what %%~xi gives how to drop the "." [dot] from the file extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=|" %%i IN ('dir /b *.*') do if not %%~xi==.bat echo %%i
```

I have added `tokens=*` in as well otherwise you won't get full filenames if they have spaces.

To echo without the dot

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=|" %%i IN ('dir /b *.*') do (
set e=%%~xi
set e=!e:.=!
echo !e!
)
```

This is providing that the file doesn't have any other dots, otherwise it will remove them too. This is a bit more sturdy than just removing the 4th character from the end though, as not all files have a 3 character extension.

Comment: Ok thanks. One side query not related to above directly.If i need just the file extension to be printed i.e. "doc" , and not ".doc" which is what %%~xi gives how to drop the "." [dot] from the file extension.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer as that is a little more tricky.

Comment: Thanks. I added below to my do command but does not work as expected. It still prints !ext! does not strip the dot. DO (
set ext=%%~xi
set ext=!ext:.=!
echo !ext!
)

Comment: Yours works fine for me, I take it these are on separate lines?

Comment: Very. I can't think what else would stop it from working. No worries :)

Comment: one last question. In your modified answer to drop the dot from file extension, since there are multiple lines we have" DO ( " , can't there be any dos command in the end after the multiple lines, and before the closing " ) " ? If i put some dos command in that multi-line DO (,  the script gives error at the line where command is mentioned. Any pointers

Comment: That should be fine, but it will run that command for all the files in the dir command. If you put what you have in your question you can format it which will make it a lot easier to see whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the output of the `dir /b` command through `findstr`, like so:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('dir /b ^| findstr /v /r "^my.bat$"') DO echo %%i
```

The `/v` option to `findstr` prints anything that doesn't match the parameter.  The match is based on a regular expression that matches only lines that contain `my.bat` and nothing else.